# Is there a way to find an element with only the final name in windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm a huge noob in windows batch and i would like to know if there is a way to find a file with the final name.

For example if I want to run a file call "myBatch.bat" but I don't know where exactly it is on my computer

Is there a command like

```
c:/*/myBatch.bat
```

Comment: Using pure MS-DOS / Windows NT utilities: `dir C:\ /s/a/b | find /i "\myBatch.bat"`. Alternatively, you may consider installing GnuWin32 and using the real `find`. And the last component of a pathname is called the _basename_ of a file.

Comment: what I want is use this in a command like run C:/MyFile/*/myBatch.bat

Comment: You cannot. Executables are either found in the current directory, or on the command search `%PATH%`, or must be explicitly located by supplying an absolute or relative pathname. And `cmd.exe` really expects \back\slashes between pathname components.

Comment: You can use the `FOR /R` command to find the file and then execute the file it finds or use the `FOR /F` command with the `DIR` command executed in the `IN` clause of the `FOR /F`.  You can also use the `WHERE` command  in the IN clause of the `FOR /F`.

Comment: `for /F "delims=" %G in ('dir /B /S "C:\myBatch.bat"') do @echo "%~G"` and you can use `call "%~G"` instead of `echo "%~G"`.

Comment: `for /r %I in (*mybatch.bat) do @echo %~I` is a bit more efficient than `for /f`.

Comment: @rojo, but it may return wrong files, like `01myBatch.bat`...

Comment: `dir /S /A:-D "C:\myBatch.bat"` searches `C:\ `for files named `myBatch.bat`; always use the `\ `as path separator in Windows rather than the `/`!

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively search for files using `for /r`.  From a cmd console:

```js
for /r "C:\" %I in (*mybatch.bat) do @"%~I"
```

From within a .bat script:

```js
for /r "C:\" %%I in (*mybatch.bat) do call "%%~I"
```

As [aschipfl comments above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979389/is-there-a-way-to-find-an-element-with-only-the-final-name-in-windows-batch/41982724#comment71143107_41979389), this could return a false positive if you have any files named similarly, but prefixed.  For an additional sanity check you could add an `if` statement.

```js
for /r "C:\" %%I in (*mybatch.bat) do if /i "%%~nI"=="mybatch" call "%%~I"
```

In any case, `for /r` is slightly more efficient than `for /f`.